# How to install Boost.Python using homebrew (on OSX)?

Tags: python-2.7, boost, cmake, ros, boost-python

I'm trying to install Robot Operating System (ROS) Melodic on my mac (macOS 11.5.1). While compiling cv_bridge package, the compiler spit out an error related to the Boost.Python:

```
$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH=$HOME/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.2;${HOME}/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated" -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17 --pkg cv_bridge

.......... (some log messages are skipped)

-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.5.12050022
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.5.12050022
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /Users/yj/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/cv_bridge
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.2;/Users/yj/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated
-- This workspace overlays: /Users/yj/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated
-- Found PythonInterp: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.16", minimum required is "2") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2
-- Using default Python package layout
-- Found PY_em: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/em.pyc  
-- Using empy: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/em.pyc
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /Users/yj/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/cv_bridge/test_results
-- Found gtest: gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.29
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- Found PythonLibs: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib (found version "2.7.16") 
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake:141 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "boost_python"
  (requested version 1.76.0) with any of the following names:

    boost_pythonConfig.cmake
    boost_python-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "boost_python" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "boost_python_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "boost_python" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake:258 (boost_find_component)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.21.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:594 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/yj/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/cv_bridge/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/yj/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/cv_bridge/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated", line 169, in <module>
    main()
  File "./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated", line 164, in main
    override_build_tool_check=opts.override_build_tool_check,
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 1071, in build_workspace_isolated
    _print_build_error(package, e)
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 810, in _print_build_error
    cprint("@{rf}@!<==@| Failed to process package '@!@{bf}" + package.name + "@|': \n  " + e_msg)
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 128, in cprint
    print(fmt(msg), end=end)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_pkg/terminal_color.py", line 126, in fmt
    return t.substitute(_ansi) + ansi('reset')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/string.py", line 176, in substitute
    return self.pattern.sub(convert, self.template)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/string.py", line 173, in convert
    self._invalid(mo)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/string.py", line 146, in _invalid
    (lineno, colno))
ValueError: Invalid placeholder in string: line 2, col 437
```

It looks that the CMake was attempting to find the Boost.Python module, but it couldn't. I never installed it. So, I typed the following command to install the Boost.Python:

```
$ brew install boost-python
```

The homebrew responded:

```
$ brew install boost-python
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (osrf/simulation and homebrew/core).
==> New Formulae
cruft                      pari-galdata               pari-seadata-big
eigenpy                    pari-galpol                singularity
newrelic-infra-agent       pari-seadata               spot
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 43 formulae.

Error: boost-python has been disabled because it does not build!
```

It looks not possible to install the boost-python formula through homebrew. Then, how can I install it?

This is a short brief of my system configuration:

```
OS: macOS Big Sur (11.5.1)
Boost library is installed by homebrew (brew install boost)
boost version: 1.76.0
python version: 2.7.16
cmake version: 3.21.1
```

## Edit 1

As @BTables said, I tried this command: `brew install boost --with-python`

It looks removed. My homebrew version is 3.2.8.

```
$ brew install boost --with-python 
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (osrf/simulation and homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 121 formulae.

Usage: brew install [options] formula|cask [...]

Install a formula or cask. Additional options specific to a formula may be
appended to the command.

Unless HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP is set, brew cleanup will then be run for
the installed formulae or, every 30 days, for all formulae.

  -d, --debug                      If brewing fails, open an interactive
                                   debugging session with access to IRB or a
                                   shell inside the temporary build directory.
  -f, --force                      Install formulae without checking for
                                   previously installed keg-only or
                                   non-migrated versions. When installing
                                   casks, overwrite existing files (binaries
                                   and symlinks are excluded, unless
                                   originally from the same cask).
  -v, --verbose                    Print the verification and postinstall
                                   steps.
      --formula, --formulae        Treat all named arguments as formulae.
      --env                        Disabled other than for internal Homebrew
                                   use.
      --ignore-dependencies        An unsupported Homebrew development flag to
                                   skip installing any dependencies of any
                                   kind. If the dependencies are not already
                                   present, the formula will have issues. If
                                   you're not developing Homebrew, consider
                                   adjusting your PATH rather than using this
                                   flag.
      --only-dependencies          Install the dependencies with specified
                                   options but do not install the formula
                                   itself.
      --cc                         Attempt to compile using the specified
                                   compiler, which should be the name of the
                                   compiler's executable, e.g. gcc-7 for GCC
                                   7. In order to use LLVM's clang, specify
                                   llvm_clang. To use the Apple-provided
                                   clang, specify clang. This option will
                                   only accept compilers that are provided by
                                   Homebrew or bundled with macOS. Please do
                                   not file issues if you encounter errors
                                   while using this option.
  -s, --build-from-source          Compile formula from source even if a
                                   bottle is provided. Dependencies will still
                                   be installed from bottles if they are
                                   available.
      --force-bottle               Install from a bottle if it exists for the
                                   current or newest version of macOS, even if
                                   it would not normally be used for
                                   installation.
      --include-test               Install testing dependencies required to
                                   run brew test formula.
      --HEAD                       If formula defines it, install the HEAD
                                   version, aka. main, trunk, unstable,
                                   master.
      --fetch-HEAD                 Fetch the upstream repository to detect if
                                   the HEAD installation of the formula is
                                   outdated. Otherwise, the repository's HEAD
                                   will only be checked for updates when a new
                                   stable or development version has been
                                   released.
      --keep-tmp                   Retain the temporary files created during
                                   installation.
      --build-bottle               Prepare the formula for eventual bottling
                                   during installation, skipping any
                                   post-install steps.
      --bottle-arch                Optimise bottles for the specified
                                   architecture rather than the oldest
                                   architecture supported by the version of
                                   macOS the bottles are built on.
      --display-times              Print install times for each formula at the
                                   end of the run.
  -i, --interactive                Download and patch formula, then open a
                                   shell. This allows the user to run
                                   ./configure --help and otherwise
                                   determine how to turn the software package
                                   into a Homebrew package.
  -g, --git                        Create a Git repository, useful for
                                   creating patches to the software.
      --cask, --casks              Treat all named arguments as casks.
      --[no-]binaries              Disable/enable linking of helper
                                   executables (default: enabled).
      --require-sha                Require all casks to have a checksum.
      --[no-]quarantine            Disable/enable quarantining of downloads
                                   (default: enabled).
      --skip-cask-deps             Skip installing cask dependencies.
      --appdir                     Target location for Applications (default:
                                   /Applications).
      --colorpickerdir             Target location for Color Pickers (default:
                                   ~/Library/ColorPickers).
      --prefpanedir                Target location for Preference Panes
                                   (default: ~/Library/PreferencePanes).
      --qlplugindir                Target location for QuickLook Plugins
                                   (default: ~/Library/QuickLook).
      --mdimporterdir              Target location for Spotlight Plugins
                                   (default: ~/Library/Spotlight).
      --dictionarydir              Target location for Dictionaries (default:
                                   ~/Library/Dictionaries).
      --fontdir                    Target location for Fonts (default:
                                   ~/Library/Fonts).
      --servicedir                 Target location for Services (default:
                                   ~/Library/Services).
      --input-methoddir            Target location for Input Methods (default:
                                   ~/Library/Input Methods).
      --internet-plugindir         Target location for Internet Plugins
                                   (default: ~/Library/Internet Plug-Ins).
      --audio-unit-plugindir       Target location for Audio Unit Plugins
                                   (default:
                                   ~/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components).
      --vst-plugindir              Target location for VST Plugins (default:
                                   ~/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST).
      --vst3-plugindir             Target location for VST3 Plugins (default:
                                   ~/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3).
      --screen-saverdir            Target location for Screen Savers (default:
                                   ~/Library/Screen Savers).
      --language                   Comma-separated list of language codes to
                                   prefer for cask installation. The first
                                   matching language is used, otherwise it
                                   reverts to the cask's default language. The
                                   default value is the language of your
                                   system.
  -q, --quiet                      Make some output more quiet.
  -h, --help                       Show this message.
Error: invalid option: --with-python
$ brew --version
Homebrew 3.2.8
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 6614f2a9b0; last commit 2021-08-18)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, I tried the following command and I worked:

```
$ brew install boost-python3
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if ROS's cmake is set up to detect/use it since your other detections are for python2, but there is a another cask for python3:  brew install boost-python3

Comment: I need python 2.7 because it is known that python 2.7 is best compatible with ros melodic.

Answer (score 0):

Run `brew install boost --with-python` then do `brew install boost-python`.

I would also like to warn you that running Melodic(or really any OSX release of ROS) isn't something I would recommend. Specifically with OSX, the build is pretty experimental and not exactly stable or complete.

Comment: Thanks @BTables. I tried the command. But, --with-python option is not available.

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2022

As @minari kotori mentioned, `brew install boost --with-python` does not build.

However, you can try building both boost and boost-python from source:

```
brew install --build-from-source -vd boost boost-python
```

If this doesn't work, you can try if `boost_python3` solves your problem:

`brew install boost`
and then
`brew install boost_python3`.

Worked for me on macOS Monterey.